# SQL returns double data (probably wrong SQL query)

Tags: mysql, sql

**problem && context**

I'm getting double results. Table Registration contains 2 columns & 2 rows,`event_id`, `participant_id` having `1,3` and `1,1`.

Now when I select all registrations (`select * from registration`) this does work.

The names `(firstname, lastname)` of the 2 participants are `('test' ,'test1')` and `('Gregor', 'unknown')`.

**desired results**

I want to make a searchfunctionality that will return just the participants that registered them for an event with the 'test' in their first or lastname.

**current results**

With the query below I get 4 results (all the same participant).

```
select * from participant p, event e, registration r 
            where p.firstname LIKE '%test%'
            OR p.lastname LIKE '%test%' 
            AND p.id = r.participant_id 
            AND e.id = r.event_id 
            AND e.id = 1;
```

**error messages**

none, just returns 4 rows instead of 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unwrapped `OR`, and a distinct will help... Try

```
select distinct * 
from participant p, event e, registration r 
where (p.firstname LIKE '%test%'
  OR p.lastname LIKE '%test%' )
AND p.id = r.participant_id 
AND e.id = r.event_id 
AND e.id = 1;
```